# Open access signal processing journal?

Tags: discrete-signals

*Signal processing* is Elsevier, so it's not open access, and *IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing* is also not open access. I was wondering if there's any decent journal on par with those that's open access.

I'm trying to submit a paper on discrete time nonlinear filtering.

(there are no tags relating to publication/journal/conference please feel free to add tags or suggest different SE)

Comment: I believe that there is an "Academia" SE forum that you could try, but you probably have a better shot with this one.

Comment: @JimClay True. If nobody here answers, I'll try over there.

Comment: Here's a great video-comic from PhD Comics arguing the benefits of open access and commenting on the current state of scientific publishing system: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5rVH1KGBCY&feature=player_embedded) Does not really help you, but it's related and very good :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The EURASIP Journal on Advances in Signal Processing is a Springer journal with open access.  It sounds like the topic of your paper is appropriate for it.  The impact factor is not as high as IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing though.